# Can't install VS 13 Community

Tags: visual-studio

Got an error thats says i have an VS 13 premium

Log here:

http://pastebin.ru/NMCjzeNz

Reinstalling the VS13 using installer don't solve problem.

HOWTO?!

Comment: Did you uninstalled VS 2013 Pro ?

Comment: yes i did it. Ill update log i put an old one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2013 Pro and VS 2013 Community Edition are essentially the same product. With the only difference being licensing terms, there are undoubtedly conflicts between components.

> **Q**: Isn’t Visual Studio Community really just Visual Studio
>   Professional?
>
> **A**: While the two editions share the same features
>   today, the licensing terms determine who can use this product. We
>   continue to invest in our paid offerings including MSDN subscription
>   benefits and services, which many Visual Studio Professional users can
>   take advantage of today.

[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dorischen/archive/2014/11/12/q-amp-a-on-visual-studio-community-2013-and-2015-preview.aspx)

Comment: Ok. Than how i can just make Android and PC tabs in VS 13 Professional?
And i got error while installing Language pack (RUS) - says i already have it. but there is no one RUSSIAN in Language's menu - only English.

Comment: This may help with the language pack issue. http://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2013/12/18/error-quot-the-language-is-already-installed-quot-when-installing-visual-studio-2013-language-packs/

Comment: Since they are the same product, couldn't you just uninstall VS 2013 Pro and install the community edition that comes with the extensions you need already installed?

Comment: i have uninstalled  VS 13  then started to install VS Community and it says that i have an VS 13 PRO installed but i dont!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting between uninstalling vs 2013 and installing the community edition?  The OS may need a reboot to finish cleaning up from the uninstall.